# How to push values into formula expression using angular

Tags: html, angularjs

i have a formula like `a+b+1500+c` or `a*b+1500` any matchematical expression  i have  values of a, b and c,
 and i declared values for a,b,c in angular script . how to push a,b ,c values in expression 
 i have tried but not getting  i posted in my previous questions also but no reply,
can you please suggest how to do this formula calculation

i have text box , on change of this text box  i want calculate  formula and bind result

view

```
  Formula:<input type="text" ng-model="Formula" ng-blur="CalculateFormula(Formula)" />

    {{result}}
```

Angular

```
 var a = 12;
    var b = 20;
    var c = 8;
    $scope.CalculateFormula = function (Formula) {
       //on change am getting formula here ex. a+b+1500+c how to push a, b, c values in this expression

    }
```

can you please suggest how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the user to type in a valid mathematical formula in the box and have the result posted to the `{{result}}` variable then all you need to do is:

```
$scope.CalculateFormula = function (Formula) {
        //on change am getting formula here ex. a+b+1500+c how to push a, b, c values in this expression
        $scope.result = eval(Formula);
    }
```

This will work for any valid mathematical formula including your a,b and c variables such as a*b+c (result = 248)

Comment: Thanks DeclanMcD its working , how can i  split an expression by arithmatic operator, am splitting only if operator is +  by using this split method  $scope.Matches = Formula.split('+'); how can i split if formula has * - and / all in that method

Answer (score 0):

check working plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/e5Ts95hFvx3rcVguefzs?p=preview

to calculate formula

```
$scope.CalculateFormula = function(formula){
  $scope.result = eval(formula);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an FYI, using eval on user input can present a somewhat large security risk ... for example if you enter

```
alert('test')
```

You will notice the string gets evaluated as javascript and an alert pops up. This allows users to run any JS they want on this un-secure input.

So you should validate the input first before using eval. Something like [MathJS](http://mathjs.org/) will handle this validation for you.

Example using MathJS eval:

```
$scope.CalculateFormula = function (Formula) {
    //on change am getting formula here ex. a+b+1500+c how to push a, b, c values in this expression
    $scope.result = math.eval(Formula);
}
```

MathJS also has a ton of other useful (and safe) helpers for common math operations.